# Goland crashes and shuts down

Tags: goland

After I open Goland and leave a project open for a while, like 10 minutes and sometimes less, Goland just closes down without any notice. I thought it could be related to the settings, especially to those related to memory as shown here:
Xms128m
    -Xmx750m
    -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
    -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
    -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
    -ea
    -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
    -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
    -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
    -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
    -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow

Is there any setting I can change to stop this sudden closing? 
I am on Windows 10, build 17134

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ask your question on our [official support tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go), and provide the IDE logs via "Help | Compress Logs and Show in...". If the zip is too large to upload then please use the [upload service](https://uploads.services.jetbrains.com/) and specify the file name in the ticket.
I cannot provide any further help here due to the nature of the issue, sorry.